# Auto numbering of Angularjs ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating student report list with Angularjs ng-repeat. My issue if how i can dynamically appending numbering like ordered-list to the generated list in view.
I want to achieve something like this

```
 # | Name of student | Student ID
 _________________________________
 1 | Samuel Addo     | 346578
 2 | GRace Asumani   | 965433
 3 | Zein Akill      | 123455
 4 | David Addoteye  | 678543
```

The '#' column should be auto generate when rendering the model in view through ng-repeat. Honestly I don't know where to start cos i don't know how to do it. I will be glad if anyone can help me or point me to the right source. Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if you clicked the '#' header, and had it reverse-sort? Or is the desired behavior that '#' column is always incrementing

Comment: it is only for numbering purpose, not intend to sort by it. thank you

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Inside ng-repeat, you can use:

```
{{$index +1}}
```

So for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students">
  <td>#{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{student.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

$index is a variable provided by the ng-repeat directive which gives you the current index. Here I added 1 to it so that the numbers start from 1 instead of 0. [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: This answer is enough for the solution. It's good (although obvious), to let user know that `{{$index}}` counts the loop indexes just like any loops in Javascript. We can do arithmetic with as well.

Comment: Waow, that was fast, thanks man. Please can you also help me on how to recalculate the model length when it is filtered. for instance if i have 10 records and i filter it by name to 4, how i can update the model length to 4? thank you again

Comment: Sorry, wrote the answer on my phone, I'll edit it now to a more complete example. Also, good to hear that helped. As for the other problem, I'm not quite sure. I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for. :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use {{$index}} to print index position for serial no inside ng-repeat.

Various other variables also available for calculation and check for first, middle, last, odd, even using $first, $middle, $last, $odd and $even respectively.

- $**index**: iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
- $**first**: true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
- $**middle**: true if the repeated element is between the first and last in
  the iterator.
- $**last**: true if the repeated element is last in the
  iterator.
- $**even**: true if the iterator position $index is even
  (otherwise false).
- $**odd**: true if the iterator position $index is odd
  (otherwise false).